# How to prevent many duplicate results after search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

when I perform a search in my wordpress site (search widget) I got pages and pages with the same result. It is not duplicate content because the results are all pointing to the exact same url. Obviously I want to display every distinct result only once.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening and what I should do about it?

**EDIT:**

Here the loop from my search.php. There is no searchform.php (as far as I know).

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $masonry_layout ) : ?>
        <div id="masonry-loop">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ( $masonry_layout ) : ?>
        </div><!--/#masonry-loop-->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: It is hard to tell why is this happening without seeing any code or settings or whatever is involved in your search query...

Comment: @Jordi, I've added some code to my question. Maybe it makes it more clear to you. It is also happening with a differtent theme. What settings do you mean? I only added the search widget to the sidebar. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Just added this snippet to m functions.php file:

```
function search_distinct() {
return "DISTINCT";
}
add_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_distinct');
```